# Request too heavy

Tags: php, symfony5

I try to retrieve for each region the number of cities with current events.

So I started doing this:

```
$regionCities = [];
foreach ($regions as $region) {
    $regionCities[$region->getId()] = $cityRepository->getCitiesByRegion($region);
}
 
dump($regionCities);
 
$regionCitiesNumber = [];
foreach ($regionCities as $index => $region) {
    foreach ($region as $city) {
        $regionCitiesNumber[$index] = count($city->getCurrentEvents());
    }
}
```

My dump returns me this:

[dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkvuo.png)

The problem is, it crashes my script, and I suddenly get a blank page when I dump regionCitiesNumber.

getCurrentEvents is a method of my City entity that will retrieve all current events.

```
public static function createCurrentEventsCriteria(): Criteria
{
    return Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->gte('endDate', new DateTime('00:00:00')))
        ->orderBy(['id' => 'DESC'])
    ;
}

public function getCurrentEvents(): Collection
{
    $criteria = EventRepository::createCurrentEventsCriteria();
 
    return $this->events->matching($criteria);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your web servers error log to see what the actual error message is?

Comment: Do you only need the count or do you need ::all:: those data because you need to render them all at once?

Comment: the script "crashing" is probably just a huge amount of data. either memory is exhausted or runtime is exhausted. in these cases you really would want a somewhat optimized database query and a/some virtual field/s. essentially you're running a query for each city, of which you have thousands. even if this is a somewhat okay query with milliseconds of execution time, it'll sum up to seconds for all cities. add to that a lot of memory just to create the output ... well.

Answer (score 0):

Use error logs or try using "Try Catch" wrapper

```
        $regionCities = [];
        foreach ($regions as $region) {
            $regionCities[$region->getId()] = $cityRepository->getCitiesByRegion($region);
        }

        //dump($regionCities);

        try {
            $regionCitiesNumber = [];
            foreach ($regionCities as $index => $region) {
                foreach ($region as $city) {
                    $regionCitiesNumber[$index] = count($city->getCurrentEvents());
                }
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $t) {
            dd($t);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried:

```
return $this->events->matching($criteria)->count();
```

And I dumped on regionCitiesNumber, it gave me a totally wrong result:

For example for the ARA region, I end up with 0 as a result while there are 1895 events distributed over all the departments ...

As a result, most regions result in 0, sometimes 1, sometimes 2 ...

In addition, it takes a long time to load my page, isn't there a softer solution?

Comment: please add stuff like this to your question as an update at the bottom, because nobody likes to look into the answers to see additions to the question ;o)